# read Ctrl+q in PowerShell ISE

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script that asks user to provide input or press Ctrl+Q to exit a menu.
How can I read a key that the user has pressed?

I found a method [Console]::ReadKey() method but that does not work for the ISE, it works only for the console.

Answer (score 2):

There's a `$host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey()` method but unfortunately [ISE does not implement it](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/713218/host-ui-rawui-readkey-not-implemented-in-version-3-ctp2) or its other overload.  ISE is not a console app, so I'm not surprised that [Console]::ReadKey() doesn't work.

You can reach down into the Win32 API to accomplish this.  This assumes PowerShell v3 or higher:

```
Add-Type -MemberDefinition @'
    [DllImport("User32")]
    public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);
'@ -Name NativeInterop -Namespace KbdUtil

$VK_CONTROL = 0x11
$Q_KEY = 0x51

"Press Ctrl+Q to exit"
while (([KbdUtil.NativeInterop]::GetAsyncKeyState($VK_CONTROL) -band 0x8000) -eq 0 -or 
       ([KbdUtil.NativeInterop]::GetAsyncKeyState($Q_KEY) -band 0x8000) -eq 0) 
{
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
}
"Done waiting"
```

Comment: This is really useful! I've been disappointed with ISE's missing `[Console]::ReadKey()` method, but this will serve as an adequate replacement, provided I only want to listen for a small subset of [all possible key codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes).